# Как инициализировать класс контроллер в Gluon Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx

Такой вот простой вопрос, но у меня как обычно ничего не работает... В общем я пишу вот такой метод в своём Main классе:

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
}
```

И, насколько я понял, теперь этот класс должен отображаться вот здесь ->

[image: Scene Builder]
Почему его там нет? Может я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Его там нет ибо Вы его должны туда вписать сами.

Для контроллеров создается отдельный класс и указывается в том поле и сохраняется `fxml`.

Вот пример контроллера:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

   @FXML
   private AnchorPane pane;

   @FXML
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
       // your code here...
   }

}
```

Метод `initialize` вызывается после того как будет загружен и проинициализированны все поля класса. Там можно писать свою логику, вешать обработчики событий.
В поля класса с аннотацией `@FXML` будет подставлен объект того компонента, который указан в `fxml` файле со свойством `fx:id`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но проблема оказалась в том, что Scene Builder заново создавал мой FXML файл, когда я его сохранял, только в другой папке (класс контроллер тогда ещё в другой папке был)... То есть fxml-файл уже находился в нужной мне папке, но сохранялся в другую