# No controller specified for top level element

Tags: java, javafx, gui, scene-builder

Через Scene Builder добавил кнопку, и в поле `onAction` добавил `cancelClick`. В классе контроллера привязал кнопку и написал обработку клика, но idea ругается!

В сети ответов мало очень...

```java
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button cancelButton;
    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private void cancelClick(){
        loginButton.setText("YES!");
    }
}
```

FXML

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="cancelButton" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancelClick" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="145.0" text="Cancel" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="26.0" />
         </font></Button>
      <Button fx:id="loginButton" layoutX="337.0" layoutY="290.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="145.0" text="Login" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="26.0" />
         </font></Button>
      <Label layoutX="123.0" layoutY="51.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Login:">
         <font>
            <Font size="40.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="123.0" layoutY="165.0" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="181.0" text="Password:">
         <font>
            <Font size="40.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <PasswordField layoutX="123.0" layoutY="227.0" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="358.0" />
      <TextField layoutX="122.0" layoutY="114.0" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="358.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Сам #cancelClick подсвечивается красным, и рекомендаций для исправления ошибки от среды разработки нет.

```java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
/D:/IntelijiProjects/out/production/IntelijiProjects/sample/sample.fxml:15

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:565)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:607)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:778)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка буквально переводится так: "в элементе верхнего уровня не указан контроллер".

Это значит что в fxml в теге `AnchorPane` (он у вас элемент верхнего уровня) нужно добавить атрибут `fx:controller="Controller"`, где `Controller` - имя вашего класса контроллера.

Это можно сделать и через Scene Builder, не редактируя fxml вручную. Например на скриншоте из [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052936/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-gluon-scene-builder) соответствующее поле обведено красным, туда нужно вписать имя класса контроллера:

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

В строчку `<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">` добавьте информацию о контроллере
`fx:controller="sample.Controller"`, тогда идея при наведении на красный `#cancelClick` предложит создать метод в этом контроллере. 
Сам метод должен выглядеть примерно вот так (на счет модификатора доступа не помню, может и private подойдет).

```
@FXML
public void cancelClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

}
```